# Does a form button force the page to reload?

Tags: php, forms, button

Is there something about a form button that forces the page to refresh?

I'm using form buttons to run a php script that modifies the content of a text file on the server. The code below writes a new value to a text file on the server named "galleryRand.txt". Then it calls the function "slideShow()" to load a *new* slideshow based on the new value of galleryRand.

This is the code that writes the new value to galleryRand:

```
<li> <span>
      <form method="post"> 
      <img src="images/btns/hotrods-40px.png" width="40px" height="40px"></a>
      <input style="vertical-align:85%;overflow:visible;font-size:1em;font-weight:bold;" 
      name="button2" type="submit" value="Arizona Hot Rods">
      </form>
<?php 
      if(isset($_POST['button2'])) { 
      $myfile = fopen("galleryRand.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
      $txt = "112"; /*hotrods*/
      fwrite($myfile, $txt);
      fclose($myfile);
      slideShow();
    } 
 ?>
</span></li>
```

Below is the code that loads the new slideshow based on the new value of galleryRand.txt:

```
<?php
function slideShow() {
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'prescoy4_vlis613', 'mysql44', 'prescoy4_pMediaDB')or die("Could not connect to host.");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
    } 
    $rNum = file_get_contents ('galleryRand.txt');
    if ($result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `setGallery` WHERE `rand` = $rNum")) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $showLoader = $row['images'];
    }}
    else
    {echo'<h2> Search Result</h2>';}
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_close($con); 
    echo '<iframe src="http://www.prescottmedia.com/html5/CONTENT/shows/562s/';
    echo $showLoader;
    echo '.html" width="562px" height="320px" align="left name="targetframe" allowtransparency="true" 
    scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>';
    }
    ?>
```

It almost works. The slideshow does change. The problem is that it takes **2 clicks** of the button to make that happen. When I use web developer tools to see what's happening, I noticed that every click of the button loads the *whole page* again. Not just the slideshow.

Any ideas about what might be going on?

Comment: Well, ya, that's what forms do.  They post a request to the form action.  If you just want to get some data from the server without reloading the page then you'd likely want to consider using AJAX and focus a bit more on JavaScript code.  It sounds like you may have designed your overall setup and logic with a misunderstanding about the technology you're using.

Comment: You might find this article informative: [MDN - Sending forms through JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript). It describes how you can "prepare an HTTP request to send via JavaScript" and thereby "use HTML forms to send data without loading a new document".

Comment: The order of operations *loosely* goes like: `Client -> Request -> Web Server -> PHP -> Response -> Client -> CSS, HTML, ECMAScript -> Render` As you can see PHP is processed when the request is received by the web-server, which is then sent back to the browser/client, that renders the received html response. Meaning the raw PHP code is never transmitted back to the browser, unlike HTML, CSS and ECMAScript which are. However this is a very basic description of HTTP 1.0/1.1, See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Comment: Thanks guys, things to think about. And David is right; as a "recovering Flash addict" I'm having a lot of problems working in the HTML, JavaScript, CSS, PHP, etc. environment. I will check out the links you suggest.